# Is it safe to remove tmp files from wamp/tmp/ folder

Tags: wamp, temporary-files

I have a few Gigs worth of files inside my `C:\wamp\tmp` folder. Is there any reason why I should not remove these files?

Comment: Couldn't you temporarily move them somewhere else and figure this out yourself?

Comment: No reason at all. Just make sure you stop WAMPServer first, and there will be no problem